# select2 : delete the element selected by pressing delete key

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 to present an editable selectbox, but when I press the delete key, in my controler I do not detects the scope of change

```
<select id="mySelect" ui-select2="{ allowClear: true}"  ng-model="select2">
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
    <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

and in my controler i write :

```
$('#mySelect').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        console.log('Delete Key Pressed');
    }
});
```

someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Get the select value using jquery and get option using selected value.

```
var selected= $('#mySelect').val();//get value
$( "option[value='"+selected+"']" ).remove();//delete option with value selected
$('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex',0);//clear select
```

Implementation example.

```js
$('#mySelect').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46) {
        var selected= $('#mySelect').val();
        $( "option[value='"+selected+"']" ).remove();
        $('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex',0);
      
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" ui-select2="{ allowClear: true}"  ng-model="select2">
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
    <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for response, but i want to deselect element when pressing  delete key ; it works when i writing :    $('html').keyup(function(e){
});
but i want using $('#mySelect')  instead $('html')

Comment: ok if you need deselect and not delete use only `$('#mySelect').prop('selectedIndex',0);`

Comment: If you need check that you are working inside select, sometimes select2 change your select by other container.

Comment: in fact when I use $('html').keyup .. everything works fine, but I only want to deselect if the combo box is already selected ($('#mySelect').)

Comment: Work in html because the event is to option, but select 2 uses an span, I think that you must set the event to the select 2 form

Comment: Give me your code example running in jsfiddle please, for see what happen.